# m/d/yyyy and mm/dd/yyyy regex with leap year check

Tags: javascript, regex, date

I am using a RegEx that is perfectly validating the leap Year and days for February. But there is once scenario that I also want the validation to be matched for both m/d/yyyy and mm/dd/yyyy.

- 05/06/2000 - Matches
- 5/6/2000 - Doesn't Match
- 02/22/2018 - Matches
- 2/22/2018 - Doesn't Match

So I want to ignore the 0's for both day and month in the below RegEx. I tried giving the ? after the 0's which makes it optional but didn't work.

```
((0[13578]|1[02])[\/.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/.](18|19|20)[0-9]{2})|((0[469]|11)[\/.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|30)[\/.](18|19|20)[0-9]{2})|((02)[\/.](0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8])[\/.](18|19|20)[0-9]{2})|((02)[\/.]29[\/.](((18|19|20)(04|08|[2468][048]|[13579][26]))|2000))
```

Any suggestions please. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: consider using a library like moment.

Comment: this isn't a good use for a regex.

Comment: I wanted to use RegEx as I only have this one scenario to be validated instead of using a library. @DanielA.White. Any suggestions on editing this RegEx?

Comment: What are you validating here, that the date is within a leap year or that it is a leap year day in Feb?

Comment: It is working fine for the days in Feb and also Leap year. The only scenario to be checked is for m/d/yyyy and mm/dd/yyyy. It should match both the cases. @DominicTobias

Comment: As @Kooilnc answered it's much simpler and safer if you put the date in a date object and check it for leap year stuff. I'm sure there's plenty of google answers about that too, no need for moment lib if you don't have it added

Answer (score 4):

A bad way of checking for leap years. Use the Date Object itself:

```js
(() => {
  const isLeapYear = year => new Date(Date.UTC(year, 1, 29)).getMonth() === 1;
  console.log( isLeapYear(2000) );
  console.log( isLeapYear(2001) );
})();
```